# Scala Bound checking

Tags: scala

I am confused about this sentence "If the identifier is bound to a thunk or a text". How can I check that? I have code where identifier is an extension of expression, while thunk and text are of type values. I have this code here but when I run it, I get a stackoverflow error.

```
package expression
import context._
import value._

case class Identifier(val name: String) extends Expression{ 
  override def toString = name
  /*def execute(env: Environment): Value = {
    env(this)

  }*/

  def execute(env:Environment): Value = 
  {
    val envThis = env(this)//wrong here
    println(this.getClass)

    if(envThis.isInstanceOf[Text])   
    {
      //println(envThis.asInstanceOf[Text].body.getClass) identifier class type
      envThis.asInstanceOf[Text].body.execute(env) //wrong here
    }
    else if(envThis.isInstanceOf[Thunk])
    {
      envThis.asInstanceOf[Thunk].apply()
    }
    else
    {
      env(this)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where does this sentence you're confused about come from?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell without knowing more about the context, but perhaps you should be looking up the *name* of the identifier in the environment, rather than the `Identifier` instance?

It would certainly be much clearer to use a `match` statement, something like this:

```
def execute(env: Environment): Value =
{
  val envThis = env(name)
  println(this.getClass)

  envThis match {
    case text: Text =>
      text.body.execute(env)
    case thunk: Thunk =>
      thunk()
    case other =>
      other
  }
}
```